# Error when deploying express socket.io to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, deployment

I am having trouble deploying a web game to a server. I have a node.js server and vanilla javascript client which are communicating with socket.io and express. I'll paste the key bits of code below.

My problem is:

- It works fine when testing on my laptop. I open up index.html, which loads server.js, which immediately connects to localhost:8080. Meanwhile I have `node ./server.js` running in Terminal, where I see all the correct console logs. The game plays as intended.
- When I go to deploy it on the server, I have problems. I'm pretty sure that the destinations are correct, as the server displays error messages when I navigate to the client HTML. It is obvious that the client is sending something to the server, but for whatever reason it isn't getting through. When I run the server with `NODE_DEBUG=cluser,net,http,fs,tlk,module,timers nodemon server.js` I get the errors shown below.

The 'HPE_INVALID_METHOD' error seems pretty vague. I have tried googling it with no luck. I would be happy even for any tips on how to better dig in to exactly what is going wrong / how to get better debug messages.

Thanks in advance. :-)

```
// Client side
let SERVER = window.location.origin;
if (SERVER == "file://") {
    // developing locally
    SERVER = "http://localhost:8080";
} else {
    // deployed
    SERVER = // server address
}
var connectionOptions =  {
        "force new connection" : true,
        "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity", //avoid having user reconnect manually in order to prevent dead clients after a server restart
        "timeout" : 10000, //before connect_error and connect_timeout are emitted.
        "transports" : ["websocket"]
    };
let SOCKET = io(SERVER,connectionOptions);
```

```
// Server Side
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const fs = require("fs");
const os = require("os");
const server = http.Server(app).listen(8080);
const io = socketIo(server);
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  // do stuff
}
```

And here are the errors I see in the server terminal:

```
NET 3337164: onconnection
NET 3337164: _read
NET 3337164: Socket._handle.readStart
HTTP 3337164: SERVER new http connection
HTTP 3337164: SERVER socketOnParserExecute NaN
HTTP 3337164: parse error [Error: Parse Error: Invalid method encountered] {
  bytesParsed: 0,
  code: 'HPE_INVALID_METHOD',
  reason: 'Invalid method encountered',
  rawPacket: <Buffer 16 03 01 02 00 01 00 01 fc 03 03 30 52 c2 a5 c7 4b 37 8d 09 f6 0f 56 9c 52 58 d7 d1 57 04 09 ed 1f 25 9d f7 f6 b7 dd 37 a9 c5 40 20 e8 04 2e 17 b8 92 ... 467 more bytes>
}
NET 3337164: destroy
NET 3337164: close
NET 3337164: close handle
NET 3337164: has server
NET 3337164: SERVER _emitCloseIfDrained
NET 3337164: SERVER handle? true   connections? 1
NET 3337164: emit close
HTTP 3337164: server socket close
NET 3337164: _onTimeout
NET 3337164: destroy
NET 3337164: close
NET 3337164: close handle
NET 3337164: has server
NET 3337164: SERVER _emitCloseIfDrained
NET 3337164: SERVER handle? true   connections? 0
NET 3337164: emit close
HTTP 3337164: server socket close
```

and the error in the browser inspect:

```
socket.io.js:1562 WebSocket connection to 'wss://<address>/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:
```